# Simulating a dice throw with threadlocalrandom does not converge to the expected value

Tags: java, random, probability, random-seed, probability-theory

I was trying to verify the [expected value formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) in java.
I did something very trivial, I simulated the roll of a dice, but I mapped each side to a specific value. So each value has probability of 1/6.
The expected value was determined as: `232.65`
I run the dice simulation a very long number of runs, `10000000` to be precise but the number did not converge to `232.65` but was `232.74`. Smaller runs also were fluxuating up to the value `233.97`. Runs up to `2100000000`gave `232.63`.
So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. My main premise here is that I shouldn't need to simulate 2 billion throws of a dice to eventually the expected value calculated via the formula.
So I am wondering if I am using the wrong random API. I can not get the seed so I can't verify if that changes per iteration. My code is the following:

```
Map<Integer, Float> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 17.2f);
map.put(2, 11f);
map.put(3, 128f);
map.put(4, 1f);
map.put(5, 1200f);
map.put(6, 38.7f);

double sum = 0;
int count = 0;

for(Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry: map.entrySet()) {
     sum += (entry.getValue() * (1/6f));
}

System.out.println("EV " + sum);
sum = 0;

for(int j = 0; j < 2100000000; j++) {
    int dice = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 7);
    sum += map.get(dice);
    ++count;
}
System.out.println(sum / count);
```

Output:

> EV 232.65000109374523
> 232.63201358102154

I was expected after a much earlier number of runs I would consistently get something ~232.650...

**Update after the comments**
Tried using `BigDecimal` but there was no difference:

```
//double sum = 0;
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
int count = 0;

for(Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    sum = sum.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(entry.getValue() * (1/6f)));
}

System.out.println("EV " + sum);

sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);

for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {
    int dice = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 7);
    sum = sum.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(map.get(dice)));
    ++count;
}

System.out.println(sum.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(count)));
```

Output:

> EV 232.6500010937452306
> 232.3528356843933100044325

Comment: do you have any particular reason to use `ThreadLocalRandom` over the usual `Random`? I don't think it makes much of a difference, just wondering.

Comment: For something like this where exactness is important, you’re better off with BigDecimals than with floats and doubles. Try them, and for the final division be sure to specify the scale explicitly.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: just convenience since it provides an API for specific bounds

Comment: @Yonas: So you think it is about floating precision? Is it about the final division or the summation?

Comment: @Jim Yes. Division definitely. Summation possibly - which is why it is wise to just use BigDecimals in these cases just to be sure, unless performance is a really really critical aspect.

Comment: @Yonas: I tried with `BigDecimal` but there was not much improvement. Please have a look at my updated

Comment: Your code gave me 232.65872728780815 as result on the first run. Take into account that random numbers in computers are not really random.

Comment: @m0skit0: What do you mean "on the first run"?

Comment: Your (updated) code looks fine. I'm guessing the results are to be expected, considering this particular sequence has quite a slow (less-than-linear) convergence rate. Also take @m0skit0 's remark into account.

Comment: The first time I ran your code.

Comment: @m0skit0 note that PRNGs do a much better job of producing IID uniform variates than almost anything else.  hardware RNG's tend to have bias/correlations and are hence fed through routines to "[whiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor)" them.  CSPRNGs increase the difficulty in predicting subsequent values (e.g. the mersenne twister only takes 624 outputs to recover its state), while a hardware RNGs should always be unpredictable.  any reasonable algorithm should produce uniform variates

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what you should expect, see the [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) on wikipedia for more info.

In your case, you have a mean of 232.65 and a standard deviation of ~434.65.  To get an idea of the expected variance you can just do:

```
lower = mu - 2 * sd / sqrt(n)
upper = mu + 2 * sd / sqrt(n)
```

For `n=2100000000` this gives approximately [232.631, 232.669], consistent with the values you and m0skit0 observed.  In general, you should expect to see a value outside of this bound approximately 1/20'th of the time, i.e. this is roughly a [95% CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval).  If you don't then the RNG isn't choosing alternatives uniformly at random.

The "slow" convergence you're experiencing is due to the `sqrt(n)`, i.e. it takes 100 times as much work to give you another decimal digit of precision.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. Where is `sqrt(n)` in my code being used?

Comment: @Jim it's a standard result from statistics that applies here.  I changed the first link to point somewhere more appropriate which has an explanation, or see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36113/17060 and linked answers there for more detail